# AJAX/XSL: Using POST parameters in XSLT

Tags: ajax, xslt, post, parameter-passing

I'm sending POST parameters to an XSLT stylesheet via AJAX.

AJAX snippet:

```
//param name/value is nodeid=1
xhttp.open("POST",dname,false);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhttp.send(params);
```

XSL snippet

```
<xsl:param name="nodeid" /> 
<xsl:template match="/">
    Hi <xsl:value-of select="$nodeid" />
</xsl:template>
```

"Hi" is coming back in the response, but not the nodeid. This seems pretty straightforward, so what am I missing? I've tried it running locally as well as on JRun/Coldfusion. Thoughts?

Comment: You haven't shown the XML document on which the transformation is applied, haven't shown the transformation itself, haven't shoun the definition and value of `$nodeid`, haven't shown who and how invokes the transformation, haven't shown the result of the transformation. This isn't a question at all. Please modify your question and provide complete information so that people would not have to guess.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question, but no need to be combative. The XML document is irrelevant as I'm not asking about the transformation of the XML, I'm asking why the above isn't able to get the value of the "nodeid" parameter passed in the AJAX call above (see the JS comment indicating the nodeid value being passed in as equal to 1). As I said, the value "Hi" which you see in the XSL snippet is being passed back to the browser via the AJAX call, but the param $nodeid is not getting the value from the POST.

Comment: The dynamics is not clear. What is executed first and what second: the HTTPRequest or the XSLT transformation. Also, it isn't clear how is the `$nodeid` param passed to the XSLT transformation -- if this is an external parameter, the way it is passed on invocation of the transformation is implementation -dependent and varies from vemdor to vendor.

Comment: Based on the provided information, you are not setting externally the XSLT parameter `$nodeid` before the invocation of the transformation. You need to read the documentation of the particular XSLT processor you are using and learn how to set an XSLT param externally. This clearly belongs to the "xsltprocessor" tag, not to the "xslt"  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use a processor specific API to get the `nodeid` parameter before processing. Either in PHP:

```
$transformer  = new XSLTProcessor();
$transformer->importStylesheet("foo.xsl");
$transformer->setParameter('', 'nameOfPage', $_POST['nameOfPage']);
```

or Coldfusion:

```
<cffile action="read" file="C:\CFusion\wwwroot\testdocs\simpletransform.xsl" 
variable="xslDoc"> 

<cfset mystruct={nameOfPage=request.nameOfPage}>
<cfset transformedXML = XmlTransform(mydoc, xslDoc, mystruct)> 

<cffile action="write" file="C:\CFusion\wwwroot\testdocs\transformeddoc.xml" 
output=transformedXML>
```

or VBScript:

```
nameOfString = WScript.Stdin.ReadAll
```

or Awk:

```
BEGIN { FS = "=" } ; { print $2 | xargs xsltproc foo.xsl foo.xml --param nameOfPage }
```

**References**

- [PI Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/PI_Parameters)
- [Setting Parameters for XSLTProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_XSLT_JavaScript_Interface_in_Gecko/Setting_Parameters)
- [Saxon: Calling .Net](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/saxon/index.php?title=CallingDotNet)
- [Xalan: setParameter](https://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/transformer/TransformerImpl.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)
- [XSLTProc Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xsltproc)
- [How to Write CGI Applications in Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239588)
- [Microsoft Windows 2000 Scripting Guide - Handling Input and Output](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156599.aspx)
- [Batch XSLT Transformation, find | xarg xsltproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794421)
- [Coldfusion: XmlTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e8e.html)