# Batch XSLT Transformation, find | xarg xsltproc

Tags: xslt, find, xargs

I'd like to recursively find every "foo.xml" file and on each `foo.xml` apply the xslt `bar.xsl` and save over the original foo.xml. When I run the following commands, separately, they work.

```
find . -name foo.xml
xsltproc -o foo.xml bar.xsl foo.xml
```

But, when I pipe them, nothing happens to `foo.xml`.

```
find . -name foo.xml | xargs xsltproc -o foo.xml bar.xsl
```

Comment: The above should take `./bar.xsl` apply to `/some/directory/foo.xml` and output to `./foo.xml`. You're saying that's not happening right?

Comment: @BroSlow It should output to /some/directory/foo.xml (replace original). But otherwise correct, it is not happening.

Comment: What happens if you add the verbose `-v` option to `xsltproc`?

Comment: @BroSlow The verbose output looks like it's applying the transformation; walking through each template and saying what it's doing. I think the problem is somehow related to saving the output.

Comment: Strange, maybe change the `-o` output file to something that doesn't exist and see if it gets created.

Comment: @BroSlow I think I may have figured out why. The output is being saved in the working directory from which I issue the command. How might I save the output in the directory in which the source foo.xml is?

Comment: [Added awnser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22795916/3076724)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning** both of these will obviously overwrite the xml's with the transformation as asked in the question.

With [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs) you want to do something like

```
find . -name foo.xml -print0 | xargs -I {} -0 xsltproc -o {} transform.xsl {}
```

Or with `-exec`

```
find . -name foo.xml -exec  xsltproc -o {} transform.xsl {} \;
```